# Change animation speed after it is started

Tags: xaml, animation, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

In **WPF** there was awesome [Storyboard.SetSpeedRatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605784%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) method, which could be called from code after animation was already started to update the [Timeline.SpeedRatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.speedratio%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. In **Windows 10** for **UWP** the `SetSpeedRatio` method is gone and if you try to set [Timeline.SpeedRatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.speedratio.aspx) directly after animation was started - it will just reset the animation and start it over again with updated ratio value.

So, what could be the best way to achieve the same goal in **UWP** project - change the speed of already started animation? Is it even doable now after all these changes in Windows Runtime API?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @VijayNirmal no, unfortunately. Otherwise I would have posted an answer here :)

Comment: @VijayNirmal as far as I remember I end up using https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D instead for certain animation effects - yeah drawing some UI elements kind of manually and animate them in an old fashioned way frame by frame. Can't really call this a "workaround" considering how much work it added, but I didn't found any other options back then.

Comment: Frame by frame animation, What???? You are great. Maybe, you can put a bounty. Someone may know.

Comment: @VijayNirmal I was considering to put a bounty on this question back then, but eventually come up with a conclusion that WPF/UWP animation system is kind of limited and not worth the efforts to squeeze something "sophisticated" out of it.